# if statement referring to a word errors with - [: !=: unary operator expected

Tags: if-statement

When running my bash script it spits out this error `[: !=: unary operator expected` when running through it.

In this function:

```
function undeploy {
        echo Removing ${SITE} from ${i} ....
        rm -rf /net/${i}/${JBPATH}/${FILEOLD}
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
                echo "Nothing to remove, proceeding to copy new WAR"
        else
        echo "WAR removed, waiting for Undeploy...."
        tail -1f /net/${i}/var/log/jboss/server.log | while read LINE ; do if [[ "${LINE}" =~ "Undeployed" ]] ; then if [[ ${LINE} =~ "${SITE}" ]] ; then break ; fi ; fi ; done
        check
        fi
        if [ $4 != force ]; then
        echo "Un-deployment completed ${i}. Continue?"
        read Continue
        case "${Continue}" in
        Y|y|yes|YES|Yes) echo "Continuing"
        ;;
        *) echo "Exiting"
        exit 1
        ;;
        esac
        fi
        }
```

The line `if [ $4 != force ];` then causes the error.

Does anyone know why? I have tried putting force and $4 in single and double quotes. Still no luck.

Any ideas of what has gone wrong with the syntax here?

If you require further information, please ask.

Comment: `if [ "$4" != force ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely to fail if there's no ${4} variable defined (if less than 4 variables are passed to the script). Try using case, or doing another test to see if $4 is present.

exmaple:  if [ $# -ge 4 ] ; then (your function)

if [ -n $4 ] ; then (your function)

Comment: You were right. Adding double "[[" "]]" worked for me.